# Picking ThreadPool Threads Based on Some Attribute of Callable

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Callable task which I wish to submit to an Executor:

```
public static final class PersonalTask implements Callable<Object> {

  private final String name;
  private final int sleep;

  public PersonalTask(String name, int sleep) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sleep = sleep;
  }

  @Override
  public Object call() throws Exception {
    System.out.format("My name is %s and I'm sleeping for %d seconds%n", name, sleep);
    Thread.sleep(sleep * 1000);
    return null;
  }

}
```

Each task contains the name of the person who has requested the task to be executed, and some period of sleeping. This sleep duration is a proxy for the real use-case, which invokes some expensive operation.

To facilitate these tasks, I'm using a fixed thread pool with **5 threads**:

```
private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

To illustrate my problem, I would like to submit the following to the thread pool:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  List<PersonalTask> tasks = Arrays.asList(new PersonalTask[] { 
      new PersonalTask("Bob", 10), new PersonalTask("Bob", 10), 
      new PersonalTask("Bob", 10), new PersonalTask("Bob", 10),
      new PersonalTask("Bob", 10), new PersonalTask("Bob", 10),
      new PersonalTask("Eric", 1), new PersonalTask("Janice", 2) });

  executor.invokeAll(tasks);
}
```

The output from this is:

```
My name is Bob and I'm sleeping for 10 seconds
My name is Bob and I'm sleeping for 10 seconds
My name is Bob and I'm sleeping for 10 seconds
My name is Bob and I'm sleeping for 10 seconds
My name is Bob and I'm sleeping for 10 seconds

*** PAUSE FOR 10 SECONDS ***

My name is Bob and I'm sleeping for 10 seconds
My name is Eric and I'm sleeping for 1 seconds
My name is Janice and I'm sleeping for 2 seconds
```

This is because the Bob tasks to sleep for 10 seconds saturate the 5 threads available, and the remaining tasks -- specifically those belonging to Eric and Janice -- have to wait for those to finish.

This is unfair! The large number / slow jobs Bob has submitted are saturating the available threads and are *starving* Eric and Jane.

I would like to provide the ExecutorService with a mechanism to discriminate on the tasks it is asked to schedule, so I may come up with a *fairer* solution.

I would like to keep this very simple for now. All of Bob's tasks should be processed by the same thread in the pool. To keep this simple, I'd like to take `PersonalTask.name.hashCode() % threadPoolSize` and use that to pick which thread to use.

This would mean that Bob can only ever use one of the available 5 threads. This would leave the 4 remaining threads free to process other people's requests.

I realize this is not perfect, as other people with the same `hash % size` value would still be held up behind Bob. In fact, they'd now have to wait much, **much** longer as there are `6 * 10 second` jobs ahead of them in that thread's queue.

What patterns can I use in Java to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Use your own implementation of `BlockingQueue` (like a [`PriorityBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html)) and a manually constructed [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#constructor_summary) that accepts as parameter your `BlockingQueue`. In your `BlockingQueue` implementation you could keep a Set of all your existing persons (in tasks) and iterate through it and return the next available Task of the person.

Answer (score 0):

In your executor service, use a `Map<Object,Queue>` to map each User to their tasks, and relate this user to their Thread in the thread pool, maybe in another map `Map<Object,Thread>`.